# Matching for unmatched input with pcase

Tags: pcase

Does `pcase` allow performing expressions when all conditions in `pcase` fail?

For instance, consider

```
 (pcase csel  
    ("bracemk" (expression-a))
    ("expression" (expression-b)))
```

Want to cater for the condition where `csel` does not match `"bracemk"` or `"expression"`.

Comment: You can add a third `_` pattern after the other two that matches anything else.  See [`(info "(elisp) pcase Macro")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/pcase-Macro.html).

Comment: `C-h f` is your friend. *Ask Emacs* (first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, let's have a look at the docs (`C-h f pcase`).  Second para reads

> Each PATTERN expands, in essence, to a predicate to call
> on EXPVAL.  When the return value of that call is non-nil,
> PATTERN matches.  PATTERN can take one of the forms:
>
> _                matches anything.

Punchline:

```
(pcase csel  
    ("bracemk" (expression-a))
    ("expression" (expression-b))
    (_ (clean-up)))
```

should do the trick.